# How can I write RegEx to create a javascript array of each image?

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex

I am trying to create a list of images. I'm getting an ajax object back with the markup in a string. Is there a way to use regular expressions in javacript to get each image? Is there another approach that is easier?

**UPDATE**

The part of the AJAX Response I want is at the bottom

```
<script>addRow("..","..",1,"646 B","10/4/14 10:09:49 AM");</script>
<script>addRow(".DS_Store",".DS_Store",0,"6.0 kB","10/4/14 10:18:24 AM");</script>
<script>addRow("Adobe_ad_728x90.jpg","Adobe_ad_728x90.jpg",0,"27.9 kB","10/4/14 10:00:39 AM");</script>
<script>addRow("bellroy.jpg","bellroy.jpg",0,"26.1 kB","10/4/14 10:00:39 AM");</script>
<script>addRow("Hybrid_Cloud_Outgrow_anim_ad_728x90.gif","Hybrid_Cloud_Outgrow_anim_ad_728x90.gif",0,"32.9 kB","10/4/14 10:00:39 AM");</script>
```

The full AJAX response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html i18n-values="dir:textdirection">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
function addRow(name, url, isdir, size, date_modified) {
  if (name == ".")
    return;

  var root = "" + document.location;
  if (root.substr(-1) !== "/")
    root += "/";

  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var file_cell = document.createElement("td");
  var link = document.createElement("a");

  link.className = isdir ? "icon dir" : "icon file";

  if (name == "..") {
    link.href = root + "..";
    link.innerText = document.getElementById("parentDirText").innerText;
    link.className = "icon up";
    size = "";
    date_modified = "";
  } else {
    if (isdir) {
      name = name + "/";
      url = url + "/";
      size = "";
    } else {
      link.draggable = "true";
      link.addEventListener("dragstart", onDragStart, false);
    }
    link.innerText = name;
    link.href = root + url;
  }
  file_cell.appendChild(link);

  row.appendChild(file_cell);
  row.appendChild(createCell(size));
  row.appendChild(createCell(date_modified));

  table.appendChild(row);
}

function onDragStart(e) {
  var el = e.srcElement;
  var name = el.innerText.replace(":", "");
  var download_url_data = "application/octet-stream:" + name + ":" + el.href;
  e.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", download_url_data);
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}

function createCell(text) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.setAttribute("class", "detailsColumn");
  cell.innerText = text;
  return cell;
}

function start(location) {
  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  header.innerText = header.innerText.replace("LOCATION", location);

  document.getElementById("title").innerText = header.innerText;
}

function onListingParsingError() {
  var box = document.getElementById("listingParsingErrorBox");
  box.innerHTML = box.innerHTML.replace("LOCATION", encodeURI(document.location)
      + "?raw");
  box.style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<style>

  h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  tr.header {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  td.detailsColumn {
    -webkit-padding-start: 2em;
    text-align: end;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  a.icon {
    -webkit-padding-start: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a.icon:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  a.file {
    background : url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAABnRSTlMAAAAAAABupgeRAAABHUlEQVR42o2RMW7DIBiF3498iHRJD5JKHurL+CRVBp+i2T16tTynF2gO0KSb5ZrBBl4HHDBuK/WXACH4eO9/CAAAbdvijzLGNE1TVZXfZuHg6XCAQESAZXbOKaXO57eiKG6ft9PrKQIkCQqFoIiQFBGlFIB5nvM8t9aOX2Nd18oDzjnPgCDpn/BH4zh2XZdlWVmWiUK4IgCBoFMUz9eP6zRN75cLgEQhcmTQIbl72O0f9865qLAAsURAAgKBJKEtgLXWvyjLuFsThCSstb8rBCaAQhDYWgIZ7myM+TUBjDHrHlZcbMYYk34cN0YSLcgS+wL0fe9TXDMbY33fR2AYBvyQ8L0Gk8MwREBrTfKe4TpTzwhArXWi8HI84h/1DfwI5mhxJamFAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC ") left top no-repeat;
  }

  a.dir {
    background : url("data:image/png;base64,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 ") left top no-repeat;
  }

  a.up {
    background : url("data:image/png;base64,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 ") left top no-repeat;
  }

  html[dir=rtl] a {
    background-position-x: right;
  }

  #listingParsingErrorBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #fae691;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<title id="title"></title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="listingParsingErrorBox" i18n-values=".innerHTML:listingParsingErrorBoxText"></div>

<span id="parentDirText" style="display:none" i18n-content="parentDirText"></span>

<h1 id="header" i18n-content="header"></h1>

<table id="table">
  <tr class="header">
    <td i18n-content="headerName"></td>
    <td class="detailsColumn" i18n-content="headerSize"></td>
    <td class="detailsColumn" i18n-content="headerDateModified"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
<script>var templateData = {"header":"Index of LOCATION","headerDateModified":"Date Modified","headerName":"Name","headerSize":"Size","listingParsingErrorBoxText":"Oh, no! This server is sending data Google Chrome can't understand. Please \u003Ca href=\"http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry\">report a bug\u003C/a>, and include the \u003Ca href=\"LOCATION\">raw listing\u003C/a>.","parentDirText":"[parent directory]","textdirection":"ltr"};</script><script>// Copyright (c) 2010 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

/**
 * NOTE: The use of this file is deprecated. Use i18n_template2.js instead.
 *
 * @fileoverview This is a simple template engine inspired by JsTemplates
 * optimized for i18n.
 *
 * It currently supports two handlers:
 *
 *   * i18n-content which sets the textContent of the element
 *
 *     <span i18n-content="myContent"></span>
 *     i18nTemplate.process(element, {'myContent': 'Content'});
 *
 *   * i18n-values is a list of attribute-value or property-value pairs.
 *     Properties are prefixed with a '.' and can contain nested properties.
 *
 *     <span i18n-values="title:myTitle;.style.fontSize:fontSize"></span>
 *     i18nTemplate.process(element, {
 *       'myTitle': 'Title',
 *       'fontSize': '13px'
 *     });
 */

var i18nTemplate = (function() {
  /**
   * This provides the handlers for the templating engine. The key is used as
   * the attribute name and the value is the function that gets called for every
   * single node that has this attribute.
   * @type {Object}
   */
  var handlers = {
    /**
     * This handler sets the textContent of the element.
     */
    'i18n-content': function(element, attributeValue, obj) {
      element.textContent = obj[attributeValue];
    },

    /**
     * This handler adds options to a select element.
     */
    'i18n-options': function(element, attributeValue, obj) {
      var options = obj[attributeValue];
      options.forEach(function(values) {
        var option = typeof values == 'string' ? new Option(values) :
            new Option(values[1], values[0]);
        element.appendChild(option);
      });
    },

    /**
     * This is used to set HTML attributes and DOM properties,. The syntax is:
     *   attributename:key;
     *   .domProperty:key;
     *   .nested.dom.property:key
     */
    'i18n-values': function(element, attributeValue, obj) {
      var parts = attributeValue.replace(/\s/g, '').split(/;/);
      for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
        var a = parts[j].match(/^([^:]+):(.+)$/);
        if (a) {
          var propName = a[1];
          var propExpr = a[2];

          // Ignore missing properties
          if (propExpr in obj) {
            var value = obj[propExpr];
            if (propName.charAt(0) == '.') {
              var path = propName.slice(1).split('.');
              var object = element;
              while (object && path.length > 1) {
                object = object[path.shift()];
              }
              if (object) {
                object[path] = value;
                // In case we set innerHTML (ignoring others) we need to
                // recursively check the content
                if (path == 'innerHTML') {
                  process(element, obj);
                }
              }
            } else {
              element.setAttribute(propName, value);
            }
          } else {
            console.warn('i18n-values: Missing value for "' + propExpr + '"');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var attributeNames = [];
  for (var key in handlers) {
    attributeNames.push(key);
  }
  var selector = '[' + attributeNames.join('],[') + ']';

  /**
   * Processes a DOM tree with the {@code obj} map.
   */
  function process(node, obj) {
    var elements = node.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var element, i = 0; element = elements[i]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < attributeNames.length; j++) {
        var name = attributeNames[j];
        var att = element.getAttribute(name);
        if (att != null) {
          handlers[name](element, att, obj);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    process: process
  };
})();
</script><script>// Copyright (c) 2010 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Invoke the template engine previously loaded from i18n_template.js
i18nTemplate.process(document, templateData);
</script><script>start("/Users/jgs/Projects/Banner-by-Bernmeister/728x90_ads/");</script>
<script>addRow("..","..",1,"646 B","10/4/14 10:09:49 AM");</script>
<script>addRow(".DS_Store",".DS_Store",0,"6.0 kB","10/4/14 10:18:24 AM");</script>
<script>addRow("Adobe_ad_728x90.jpg","Adobe_ad_728x90.jpg",0,"27.9 kB","10/4/14 10:00:39 AM");</script>
<script>addRow("bellroy.jpg","bellroy.jpg",0,"26.1 kB","10/4/14 10:00:39 AM");</script>
<script>addRow("Hybrid_Cloud_Outgrow_anim_ad_728x90.gif","Hybrid_Cloud_Outgrow_anim_ad_728x90.gif",0,"32.9 kB","10/4/14 10:00:39 AM");</script>
<script>addRow("two-factor-solution.png","two-factor-solution.png",0,"48.4 kB","10/4/14 10:00:39 AM");</script>
```

I also tried converting the string to html using `$(ajaxData)`

[image: v]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply leverage the HTML parsing capabilities of the browser. Your code sample is too long and I did not read it, but here's what can be done.

```
var someHtml = '<ul><li><img src="test.jpg"></li></ul>',
    dom = parseHtml(someHtml),
    images = dom.querySelectorAll('img');

//log the src attribute of every image
[].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
    console.log(img.src);
});

//Returns a document fragment which contains the parsed nodes
function parseHtml(html) {
    var parserEl = document.createElement('div'),
        frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    parserEl.innerHTML = html;

    [].forEach.call(parserEl.childNodes, function (node) {
        frag.appendChild(node);
    });

    return frag;
}
```

Comment: plalx I'm sorry I was a bit misleading, the part of the AJAX response I want is near the bottom so the normal jquery DOM selector wont work. Previous I did try creating `var html = $(ajaxData);` I ended up with an object that I could not use jquery selectors on.

Comment: @user3116989 Well, show a sample of your HTML. `$` is not really an  html parser... it will try to parse your string as HTML if it thinks it's HTML, but might be confused with text nodes. Try my solution...

Comment: actually your code helped me once I defined the pareHTML function and used that.